# How to change the footer in Olsen Theme for Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
            </div><!-- /site-content -->

            <?php if ( ! is_page_template( 'template-blank.php') ) : ?>
                <footer id="footer">

                    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-widgets') ) : ?>
                        <?php
                            $attributes = sprintf( 'data-auto="%s" data-speed="%s"',
                                esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'instagram_auto', 1 ) ),
                                esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'instagram_speed', 300 ) )
                            );
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="footer-widget-area" <?php echo $attributes; ?>>
                                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-widgets' ); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="site-bar group">
                        <nav class="nav">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'footer_menu',
                                'container'      => '',
                                'menu_id'        => '',
                                'menu_class'     => 'navigation',
                                'depth'          => 1,
                            ) ); ?>
                        </nav>

                        <div class="site-tools">
                            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'footer_socials', 1 ) == 1 ) {
                                get_template_part( 'part-social-icons' );
                            } ?>
                        </div><!-- /site-tools -->
                    </div><!-- /site-bar -->
                    <div class="site-logo">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
                                <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'footer_logo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' ) ): ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'footer_logo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' ) ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" />
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </h3>

                        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'footer_tagline', 1 ) == 1 ): ?>
                            <p class="tagline"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div><!-- /site-logo -->
                </footer><!-- /footer -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

hi, I'm trying to figure out how I can customize the footer in this theme. [Olsen Theme](https://www.cssigniter.com/demo2/?theme=olsen)

This is the code from the footer.php file.  I've watched tutorials on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/9HdzTqsAfIs) but the themes shown on the tutorial are real simple to customize the footer.  But with this theme I can't figure out where to make the changes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to customise in the footer?

Comment: I want to add the copyright stuff and something similar to this https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wxfm7rnmju1l2l/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-12%20at%209.32.58%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks everyone, I figured it out ha